# Get value form elements inside div with only ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm newbie in ASP.NET and i think that my question is quite simple, but I'm not getting success in my searches through google or even stackoverflow.

I have a asp.net method (vb.net) that loads a entire html page inside a div.
Doing searches, i discovered that it can be like this:

On .aspx page:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

On .vb codebehind:

```
Private sub LoadContent()
content.InnerHtml = MyDLL.LoadFromDatabase.Value.ToString()
End Sub
```

So, nothing special until here.
But, if consider that the html code loaded from database has form elements like `<input id="name" type="text">`, my problem starts...

On page postback these  don't keep the values as  `<asp:TextBox>` created natively on code, does.

And the other thing that I want is a way to retrieve the value from them to work on codebehind, like: `myvar = content.Controls("name").Value`

At least, is there a way to solve my problem?

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks so much.

Comment: Try dynamically adding controls instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1%28v=vs.140%29.aspx, and do it very early to keep the viewstate... say during init. Otherwise you have to get the values out on postback with request.form.

Comment: @CRice, thanks for rapid reply! Based on your hint, i implemented that: `Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim txt As New TextBox
            txt.Text = Session("txt").ToString()
            content.Controls.Add(txt)
        End If
    End Sub`



    `Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
        Session("txt") = content.Controls(0). what?
    End Sub`.

I continue without manipulate the control added inside the div.

Comment: Don't use unload to get the value.  Get your textbox instance with findcontrol https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, which could be during page load.

Answer (score 1):

CRice is right. If you want the viewstate to persist through postback you need to create the controls server-side.

Careful though: I've had bad experience with dynamically created controls on Asp.Net, specifically when trying to bind events to them. Not only would you have to use delegates and events (a hard topic for a newbie), also when I tried it a few years ago I just couldn't get it to work, no matter what.

If you're going for dynamic created controls, make sure it's worth the effort, because it WILL be an effort, now and in the future when you would like to maintain and add expand. A rule of thumb is that dynamic mechanisms are always harder to maintain than static ones, but they provide more flexibility.

Having that said, if you're still going for dynamic html loading, be aware that better solutions exist, though they require different architectures: client side frameworks (best is angluar.js) provide dynamic loading of "modules" (and much more), which is what you want. On the server side, asp.net MVC with its Razor view engine, partial views etc., is better suited for dynamic html generation.

Back to your original question,are you sure you need a full postback? What about a nice neat Ajax call to a web service? Can get the job done in many cases without reloading the whole page. I guess using jquery's `$.ajax` syntax and creating a simple .asmx web service will be easiest for you.

Last but not least, why use vb.net instead of c#? It sucks man. Give it up while you still can.

Comment: +1 .. the answer I was too lazy to write. Totally agree that VB sucks. My only other thought is that an .ascx user control is a good idea when dynamically loading controls in webforms - you just need to reload the control and its state and the UI is handled.